# sqlalchemy many-to-many relationship (tag system)

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have three tables: `file`, `file_tag` and `tag`.
Now I want to find all files that have the tags with ID `1` and `3`.

[image: Table: file]
[image: Table: file_tag]
[image: Table: tag]

```
class File_Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'file_tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    file_id = Column('file_id', Integer, ForeignKey('file.id'))
    tag_id = Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tag.id'))


class File(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'file'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    tags = relationship('File_Tag')

class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tag'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255))
    files = relationship('File_Tag')
```

This is what I have:

```
session.query(File).join(File.tags).filter(File_Tag.tag_id.in_([1, 3]))
```

The problem is that it shows me all files with tag `1` OR `3`, I want to see all files with tag `1` AND `3`.

The SQL querys it produces looks like this:

```
SELECT file.id   AS file_id,
  file.name      AS file_name,
  file.sha1      AS file_sha1,
  file.import_id AS file_import_id
FROM file
INNER JOIN file_tag
ON file.id             = file_tag.file_id
WHERE file_tag.tag_id IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY file.id
```

As result I get the files `2`, `3` and `4`, but I should get just files `2` and `4`.

I dont want to use subquerys if possible, I heard they are slow ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
SELECT file.id   AS file_id,
  file.name      AS file_name,
  file.sha1      AS file_sha1,
  file.import_id AS file_import_id
FROM file
INNER JOIN file_tag
ON file.id            = file_tag.file_id
WHERE file_tag.tag_id =1
AND file_tag.file_id IN
  (SELECT file_id FROM file_tag WHERE tag_id=3
  )
GROUP BY file.id;
```

Also, an sqlalchemy should be something like:

```
subq=session.query(File_Tag).filter(File_Tag.tag_id=3);
session.query(File).join(File.tags).filter((File_Tag.tag_id=1)&(File_Tag.file_id.in(subq)))
```

It contains a subquery, but I think it is not possible to achieve what you want without using them.

Comment: This is working but I need the sqlalchemy code for that, please!

Comment: Also, I have never used sqlalchemy before, I have tried to produce the right one for you. Pls, see the edit.

Comment: I think 1 subquery per tag is ok but can you tell me to automate this if I have a `list()` of tags (from 0 to x tags). For example: `searched_tags = list(1, 3, 10, 15, ...)`.

Comment: Do you mean that you are searching for files containing all of the tags in the predefined list?

Comment: Yes. I parse the tags that I'm looking for from user input, after that I have an python list with all tags.