# SQLAlchemy many to many query filter (tag system)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a Django App and a Telegram bot that uses same database. There are 2 tables Link and Tag have many to many relation (models are below). I'm trying to query `link_id`'s where all `tag_id`'s are `[1, 8, 10]`. Query result should be `[1,4]`.

Using: SQLAlchemy 1.3.23, PostgreSQL 12.6

```
TABLE: link_tags
link_id | tag_id
--------|---------
1       | 1
1       | 8
1       | 10
..
4       | 1
4       | 8
4       | 10
```

```
class Tag(Base):
    __tablename__ = "tag"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(15), nullable=False)


link_tag_table = Table(
    "link_tags",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("link_id", Integer, ForeignKey("link.id")),
    Column("tag_id", Integer, ForeignKey("tag.id")),
)


class Link(Base):
    __tablename__ = "link"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    tags = relationship(Tag, secondary=link_tag_table)
```

There is a similar question but not a proper answer. [sqlalchemy many-to-many relationship (tag system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671675/sqlalchemy-many-to-many-relationship-tag-system)

Answer (score 0):

> Query result should be `[1,4]`

If you only need the `link_id`s and not `Link` instances, just query the association table, e.g.,:

```py
[
    id
    for id, in engine.execute(
        select([link_tag_table.c.link_id])
        .where(link_tag_table.c.tag_id.in_([1, 8, 10]))
        .distinct()
        .order_by(link_tag_table.c.link_id)
    )
]
# [1, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks but didn't work for me. This give me all values. I'm trying to understand what's the problem. I can insert new values but can't query :D

Created a new db for testing. Searching for [3, 4] and it returns [1, 2, 3]. I just need link_id 2. 
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/PfSrFTGjvt/

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved.

SQL:

```sql
SELECT link_id FROM link_tags WHERE tag_id IN (1,8,9,10)
GROUP BY link_id
HAVING COUNT(tag_id)=3
```

SQLAlchemy:

```py
session.query(link_tag_table.c.link_id)
.filter(link_tag_table.c.tag_id.in_([1, 8, 9, 10]))
.group_by(link_tag_table.c.link_id)
.having(func.count(link_tag_table.c.tag_id) == 3)
.all()
```