# How do i get an Sqlalchemy many to many efficient intersect query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two classes using Sqlalchemy: PhotoRec and Tag with a many to many relationship between them (Photo_Tag).

What I am trying to get is a query that will return all the photos that have all of the tags in a given list but the list will not necessarily have every tag in the PhotoRec tag list.

Examples:

```
photo1 with Tags ('red', 'box', 'big')
photo2 with Tags ('blue', 'box', 'small')
photo3 with Tags ('green', 'house', 'big')
photo4 with Tags ('red', 'can', 'small')
photo5 with Tags ('blue', 'box', 'large')
```

Querying photos with ('blue', 'box') would then only give me [ photo2, photo5 ]

Note: the given list is based on user input and will be a variable amount of tags.

I have it working with .intersect() but this does not appear to be very efficient:

```
for i in [55, 72]: # Tag IDs that must match
    temp_query.append( session.query(PhotoRec).filter( PhotoRec.photorec_tag.contains(session.query(Tag).get(i)) ))

temp_query[0].intersect(*temp_query[1:]).all()
```

I want somthing like one of these:

```
temp_query.append( session.query(PhotoRec).filter( PhotoRec.photorec_tag.any(Tag.id.in_([55, 72])) ))

temp_query.append( session.query(PhotoRec).join(Photo_Tag).filter(Photo_Tag.columns.tag_id.in_([55, 72])) )
```

both of these give me all photos that have any of those tags, however I want all photos with all of those tags.

the Join one is supposed to be more efficient from what I read but either one modified to work like an intersect will work for me.

I have tried a few options with all_() and other functions that give me errors and I dont seem to understand exactly how these work.

I have looked at other posts on SO and this one seems to be what I want but the answer wont work in my case:

[sqlalchemy many-to-many relationship (tag system)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671675/sqlalchemy-many-to-many-relationship-tag-system)

if the above with the .intersect() option is the best then fine I will go with that.